# GPU out of Memory using PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to use and fine tune one of the huggingface models (mobileVIT) and in order to fine tune the model, I am using Google Colab's A100 GPU which has 40Gb of GPU RAM. However, I keep running out of storage. Is it normal for PyTorch to ocupy 38Gb?

OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 1024.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacity of 39.56 GiB of which 952.81 MiB is free. Process 378486 has 38.62 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 38.07 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 54.62 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF=expandable_segments:True to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management  (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#environment-variables)

I tried changing the batch size but everytime I changed the batch size, the size of PyTorch would decrease but still not enough to allocate the necessary storeage. I would like the batch size to be at least 256. Is this possible with a 40Gb GPU?